# WizTree: Difference in values of "Total size" and "Size" of disk

Tags: storage

Here is the screen shot of the file tree of my phone's internal storage:
[image: phone's internal storage]

Why the total space available (shown at the top) is 48.8 GB but size on disk is just 20.5 GB, isn't it supposed to be 48.8 GB? How can i see the hidden 28.3 GB of files?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe others partitions / folders on the drive ? What do you have inside the `select` field of your screenshot ? - You are currently inside `2027` folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect an Android device to a PC the PC does not get access to the storage system of Android. Instead Android exposes some folders to the PC using the [Media Transfer Protocol (MTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol).

Furthermore Android uses multiple partitions, usually one or more system partition(s), and one partition for user data. The entries "Total Space" and and "Space Used" refer to this user data partition. The system partitions (depending on the device and Android version) usually have a size of about 8-25GB, thus the user data partition can only be as large as the remaining space. In your case I assume your phone has 64GB flash storage. The user data partition has 48.8GB which means the system partitions consume the other space of 15.2GB.

The user data partition there are again several sections:

- Shared storage (`/sdcard` or `/storage/emulated/0`)
- App private data (`/data/data`)

MTP only allows you to see shared storage, so the shown storage tree only covers this part of the user data partition. Therefore you only see 20.5Gb of 48.2GB via MTP.